# Invalid Incoming XCMP message data

Tags: xcm, assets, xcmp, statemint, panic

[Link to repo](https://github.com/JuaniRios/xcm-emulator/blob/xcmp-bug/xcm-emulator/xcmp-bug/src/lib.rs#:%7E:text=fn%20new_fungible_reserve_transfer()%20%7B)

I'm trying to do a reserve-backed transfer from statemint to my own parachain of a token minted with the pallet_assets. I've been using the [xcm-emulator](https://github.com/shaunxw/xcm-simulator/tree/master/xcm-emulator) that lets me plug in my own runtimes and do tests on them.

I managed to get this working, except that my parachain doesn't accept this token to pay for execution in the BuyExecution instruction (intended behaviour), so I wanted to also add some DOT tokens on the reserve_transfer_assets pallet call, and specify on the fee_asset_item parameter the index of DOT to use for paying the transaction. It looks something like this:

```rust
    StatemintParachain::execute_with(|| {
        let xcm = StatemintXcmPallet::reserve_transfer_assets(
            statemint_runtime::Origin::signed(ALICE),
            Box::new(MultiLocation{parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2000))}.into()),
            Box::new(X1(Junction::AccountId32 {
                network: NetworkId::Any,
                id: ALICE.into()
            }).into().into()),
            Box::new(vec![
                MultiAsset {
                    id: Concrete(X2(PalletInstance(50), GeneralIndex(1)).into()),
                    fun: Fungible(500)
                },
                MultiAsset {
                    id: Concrete(Parent.into()),
                    fun: Fungible(INITIAL_BALANCE/10)
                },
            ].into()),
            1,
        );
```

The problem is that when adding DOT to the assets parameter, there seems to be an XCMP decoding error on the receiving parachain side:

```
Invalid incoming XCMP message data
thread 'tests::new_fungible_reserve_transfer' panicked at 'Invalid incoming XCMP message data', /Users/juan/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/d08055d/pallets/xcmp-queue/src/lib.rs:679:25
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/4b91a6ea7258a947e59c6522cd5898e7c0a6a88f/library/std/src/panicking.rs:584:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/4b91a6ea7258a947e59c6522cd5898e7c0a6a88f/library/core/src/panicking.rs:142:14
   2: cumulus_pallet_xcmp_queue::<impl cumulus_pallet_xcmp_queue::pallet::Pallet<T>>::process_xcmp_message
             at /Users/juan/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/d08055d/pallets/xcmp-queue/src/lib.rs:679:7
   3: cumulus_pallet_xcmp_queue::<impl cumulus_pallet_xcmp_queue::pallet::Pallet<T>>::service_xcmp_queue
             at /Users/juan/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/d08055d/pallets/xcmp-queue/src/lib.rs:832:40
   4: cumulus_pallet_xcmp_queue::<impl polkadot_parachain::primitives::XcmpMessageHandler for cumulus_pallet_xcmp_queue::pallet::Pallet<T>>::handle_xcmp_messages
             at /Users/juan/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/d08055d/pallets/xcmp-queue/src/lib.rs:979:3
   5: <xcm_emulator_example::AcurastParachain as polkadot_parachain::primitives::XcmpMessageHandler>::handle_xcmp_messages::{{closure}}
             at /Users/juan/Desktop/acurast-jobs/xcm-simulator/xcm-emulator/src/lib.rs:90:28
   6: environmental::using::{{closure}}
             at /Users/juan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/environmental-1.1.3/src/lib.rs:125:3
   7: std::thread::local::LocalKey<T>::try_with
             at /rustc/4b91a6ea7258a947e59c6522cd5898e7c0a6a88f/library/std/src/thread/local.rs:445:16
   8: std::thread::local::LocalKey<T>::with
             at /rustc/4b91a6ea7258a947e59c6522cd5898e7c0a6a88f/library/std/src/thread/local.rs:421:9
   9: environmental::using
             at /Users/juan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/environmental-1.1.3/src/lib.rs:106:2
  10: sp_externalities::scope_limited::ext::using
             at /Users/juan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/environmental-1.1.3/src/lib.rs:252:5
  11: sp_externalities::scope_limited::set_and_run_with_externalities
             at /Users/juan/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/3348e14/primitives/externalities/src/scope_limited.rs:31:2
  12: sp_state_machine::testing::TestExternalities<H>::execute_with
             at /Users/juan/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/3348e14/primitives/state-machine/src/testing.rs:196:3
  13: <xcm_emulator_example::AcurastParachain as xcm_emulator::TestExt>::execute_with::{{closure}}
             at /Users/juan/Desktop/acurast-jobs/xcm-simulator/xcm-emulator/src/lib.rs:230:32
  14: std::thread::local::LocalKey<T>::try_with
             at /rustc/4b91a6ea7258a947e59c6522cd5898e7c0a6a88f/library/std/src/thread/local.rs:445:16
  15: std::thread::local::LocalKey<T>::with
             at /rustc/4b91a6ea7258a947e59c6522cd5898e7c0a6a88f/library/std/src/thread/local.rs:421:9
  16: <xcm_emulator_example::AcurastParachain as xcm_emulator::TestExt>::execute_with
             at /Users/juan/Desktop/acurast-jobs/xcm-simulator/xcm-emulator/src/lib.rs:230:13
  17: <xcm_emulator_example::AcurastParachain as polkadot_parachain::primitives::XcmpMessageHandler>::handle_xcmp_messages
             at /Users/juan/Desktop/acurast-jobs/xcm-simulator/xcm-emulator/src/lib.rs:90:5
  18: xcm_emulator_example::_process_horizontal_messages
             at /Users/juan/Desktop/acurast-jobs/xcm-simulator/xcm-emulator/src/lib.rs:381:8
  19: xcm_emulator_example::_process_messages
             at /Users/juan/Desktop/acurast-jobs/xcm-simulator/xcm-emulator/src/lib.rs:330:5
  20: <xcm_emulator_example::StatemintParachain as xcm_emulator::TestExt>::execute_with
             at /Users/juan/Desktop/acurast-jobs/xcm-simulator/xcm-emulator/src/lib.rs:272:5
  21: xcm_emulator_example::tests::new_fungible_reserve_transfer
             at ./src/lib.rs:547:3
  22: xcm_emulator_example::tests::new_fungible_reserve_transfer::{{closure}}
             at ./src/lib.rs:474:2
  23: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/4b91a6ea7258a947e59c6522cd5898e7c0a6a88f/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:248:5
  24: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/4b91a6ea7258a947e59c6522cd5898e7c0a6a88f/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:248:5
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.

error: test failed, to rerun pass '--lib'
```

I tried instead of sending DOT, to send another minted asset, and that seems to be decoded correctly on the receiving chain. What am I Missing here?

Comment: Can you provide your full code(like a repo)? So that we can reproduce your problem

Comment: https://github.com/JuaniRios/xcm-emulator/blob/xcmp-bug/xcm-emulator/xcmp-bug/src/lib.rs#:~:text=fn%20new_fungible_reserve_transfer()%20%7B

Comment: @Guantong posted the link, would you mind taking a look?

Comment: Yeah, I'll take a look

Comment: Well, it seems to be a bug

Answer (score 2):

After debugging I think it's a bug (`pallet-xcm` or `cumulus-pallet-xcmp-queue`), you can track it here: https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/issues/1700